# Modulus of a big number by a big number.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, arithmetic, computer-arithmetic

I'm trying to perform the following calculation:

$$ a\pmod m $$

where both $a$ and $m$ are numbers *larger than $32$ bits*. However, I'm only able to perform calculations on $32$ bit numbers.

So I was wondering if there is a way to compute arbitrary precision modulo.

Comment: Of course there is a way... But you'll have to use more than 32 bits if the input (and in particularly $m$) is larger than 32 bits.

Comment: Just how is this related to math? As long as math is concerned, there is absolutely nothing special about 32 or any other particular number of bits. Essentially, this is a programming question. I vaguely remember hearing that there is a special SE site dedicated to that area. Long story short, you have to define your own type and redefine the arithmetic operations for it.

Comment: Java and .NET framework (C# and others) provide BigInteger library. In C/C++ LibGMP is best for multi-precision arithmetic and number theory. Btw I think this question is out of the scope of this site and should be asked in SO or SciComp.

Answer (score 1):

The most simple way is using [*Python 2.5+*](https://www.python.org/) or [*Python 3.0+*](https://www.python.org/).

Just perform standard math operations and *any number which exceeds the boundaries of 32-bit math* will be *automatically and transparently* converted to a `bignum`.

Moreover, Python is an *interpreted* language so you may use it *as a calculator* - just write an expression an press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to see the result.

*Modulo* in Python is represented by the operator `%`.

Example:

```
>>> 999999999999999999999999999999 % 333333333333333333333
```

gives the result

```
999999999
```